# Why don't chess sites offer best of X match formats?

Tags: chess-variants

I believe chess sites should offer best of 3/5/etc match formats, rather than a one-off game. Basically, if you enter such a game, you don't "win" by just winning 1 game, you have to be the first to win 2 out of 3, or first to 3 out of 5, etc.

Why don't chess sites offer these formats?

The thing about chess is that it's a very stylistic game. You can end up playing an opening or a style that just happens to suit your opponent perfectly well, and you end up losing because of that. In these instances, being able to *adapt* your style to your opponent and win the subsequent games is a vital dispaly of ability that is best measured in best of X types of formats, rather than one-off games where you lose, and then your opponent refuses a rematch and runs away.

There's a reason why this format is used in chess finals. Yet ironically, no chess sites offer this format, instead its always one-off games with the *option to rematch*, which is obviously not optimal, since rematches can be declined.

For example, I recently played against an opponent that **clearly** had a well-prepared opening to the Ruy Lopez... he completely destroyed me, made moves I had never seen in the Ruy Lopez. Does that mean he's better at chess than me? No, it just means he's better at the Ruy Lopez. If it was a best of 3 format, I would play the second game with a very different opening indeed and not fall into the prepared trap.... i did offer a rematch but he ran away. Surprise suprrise.

Comment: There are many different reasons why someone is not doing something. Impossible to answer without inside knowledge.

Comment: From a practical standpoint, how would you handle a disconnect in a best of X series? Automatically forfeit them all remaining games seems harsh and unwarranted.  But otherwise, you can't really oblige players to commit to a full series.  So players can just quit after 1 game if they choose anyway.  Also, for random match-making purposes, adding series options further segments the player pool, which hinders good match-making.  The rematch option exists if players opt-in.  If you'd like to engage in more series, I'd recommend asking your opponent on move 1 if they're interested first.